# This page isn't working - Error 501 Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am facing an error, when I try to access the page I get the following error message:

This page isn’t working website is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 501

I am using xampp on localhost, I tried to remove the .htaccess file, it's still the same. on all controllers, but when i just print something with exit; is showing.

These are the last error logs:
[Fri Oct 23 22:46:41.404134 2020] [ssl:warn] [pid 10004:tid 680] AH01909: [www.example.com:443:0](http://www.example.com:443:0) server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name [Fri Oct 23 22:46:41.503131 2020] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 10004:tid 680] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.

Comment: This might be due to appache conf error, try this:
Open httpd-ssl.conf at here:
C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
Hash the below line, and change to “localhost”
#ServerName www.example.com:443
ServerName localhost
Save and restart apache

Comment: i did, but is not working

Comment: Try just by commenting Listen 443 (like #Listen 443)in httpd-ssl.conf file.

Comment: same, i think the problem is on my files, because if i just write echo 'something';exit; is displaying on screen